# Protractor : Element.all.getText() is retrieving only a partial list of elements

Tags: angularjs, protractor, gettext

I am trying to get the list of all the names using the below code .

```
element.all(by.css('div[class="ABC"]')).getText().then(function(lis) {
          console.log(lis);
        })
```

However , it renders me only the partial list(the rest of the list is throwing me null values ). The output is something like.

```
[
'ABC',
'DEF',
'GHI',
'JKL',
'',
'',
'',
'']
```

However the elements are populated in UI page without any null values. Can someone please help how to render the complete list ?

Comment: past html code for the list

Comment: Probably, not all elements display on UI, but exist in HTML. You could use filter() to reduce elements with a null value.